# Conditional tag in Widget Logic for checking if top level page or if subpage

Tags: plugins, widgets, conditional-tags

I'm using the [Widget Logic plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/widget-logic/) to show widgets on certain pages using Wordpress Conditional Tags (or any general PHP code).

What I would like to do is only show a widget on child pages, not top level pages. I tried both of the following but they both return true on all pages (so the widget shows on all pages):

```
global $post; return ($post->post_parent != 0);
```

and

```
global $post; return ( is_page() && $post->post_parent );
```

Note I tried this for testing and the widget displays on page ID 61 and its children, not just on its children as I was expecting:

```
global $post; return ($post->post_parent=="61");
```

Any tips?

Thanks!

Comment: how about `return ($GLOBALS['post']->post_parent != 0);` ?

Comment: I'm not sure you can use PHP like you are trying to with Widget Logic. I have used the plugin many times but never tried raw PHP. According to the Codex it should be `is_page() && $post->post_parent` but you may be constrained to the conditional tags.

Comment: Thanks guys but neither of those worked. One Trick Pony, the widget still shows on both parent and child. BandonRandon, it shows on neither.

Comment: Your syntax is correct and works as expected with widget logic. `global $post; return ( is_page() && $post->post_parent );` Double check that your pages are exclusively parent or child pages as you are expecting.

Comment: Perhaps you have the `eval` function blacklisted (that plugin relies on this naughty function)

Comment: Thanks RyanLoremIpsum, could it have anything to do with using the WPML plugin? And One Trick Pony, wouldn't that stop it ever working? You see, I have it working on other widgets with simpler arguments. Sorry if that is a silly question :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies, turns out it was a problem with my theme - using `get_posts` to list child pages outside the loop without `wp_reset_postdata`. So a `global $post;` conflict I guess.

`global $post; return ($post->post_parent != 0);` works fine.

Comment: Can you explain what the theme was doing to cause the problem?

Comment: Sure! It was using `get_posts` to list child pages outside the loop without `wp_reset_postdata`. So a `global $post;` conflict I guess.

Comment: Edit that into the answer, please. These aren't discussion forums. The answer itself should have all of the relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer on the [plugin's page](http://wordpress.org/plugins/widget-logic/other_notes/) at wordpress.org. Select the tab 'Other Notes'. You will find it at the example list:

```
global $post;

// WP page that is a child of page 77
return in_array(77, get_post_ancestors($post));
```

**Edit:** As an alternative to your suggestions you may try

```
global $post;
return !empty(get_post_ancestors($post));
```

This is an expensive call and should better be used for testing only. But I suspect that there might be something wrong with your page hierarchy. Is it possible that your top level page is not on root level?

Comment: Thanks jot but that doesn't work for me. Firstly, it still shows on both parent and child. Secondly, I really want a solution that does not have to have the parent page ID hardcoded, instead shows on any child page.

Comment: Thanks for editing your answer jot! But the second option gives me a PHP error: PHP Fatal error:  Can't use function return value in write context in ~\widget_logic.php(284) : eval()'d code on line 1